# 'This field is required.' is shown next to inputs, with GET request

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I can't get the 'This field is required.' **not** show on the page when my form is instantiated. Also, I'm using Django + Bootstrap.

forms.py

```
class RatingForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(
    label='', 
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )
rating = forms.ChoiceField(
    label='',
    widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': ''}), 
    choices=RATING_CHOICES,
    )
```

views.py function

```
thing = Thing.objects.get(name=thing_name)
rating_form = RatingForm(request.POST) # get form for adding a Rating to Thing

args={'thing':thing, 'rating_form':rating_form}
args['ratings'] = thing.ratings.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        ...
        ...
    else:
        return redirect('/')
else:
        if thing:
            # This is the page I'm loading that I'm having problems with
            return render(request, 'thing_page.html', args)
        else:
            return redirect('/')
```

html

```
<form class='form-inline' method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<label for="id_name">Create A New Rating:</label><br />
{{ rating_form|removetags:"li ul" }}
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="add rating" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only pass `request.POST` to the form for POST requests.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    rating_form = RatingForm(request.POST)
    ...
else:
    rating_form = RatingForm()
```

If you use `RatingForm(request.POST)` for a GET request, then `request.POST` is empty, so you will get errors for any required fields. Instead, you should use `RatingForm()` for a `GET` request. This creates an unbound form, so you will not get any validation errors.

See the docs on [bound and unbound forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms) for more info.

Comment: Ah! So obvious! Thanks Alasdair :)